# Generate glossary with array of title/answer

Tags: javascript

I would like generate an Glossary with a array of title / answer, based on the title first letter for insert in good alphabet letter.

Actulay, i've just a simple array with my content, but not filtered in "glossary".

So, i generate an alphabet :

```
const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');
alphabet.map(letter => <Text>{letter}</Text>
```

And my array of title / answer :

```
{glossaries.map((glossary, index) =>
  <Text>{glossary.title} / {glossary.answer}</Text>
)}
```

I get the first with `glossary.title.charAt(0)`, but i don't know how i can generate my array with this structure :

```
[
  'A': [
    {
      title: 'my title',
      answer: 'Yeah'
    },
    ...
  ],
  'B': [
    ...
  ]
]
```

Anyone know how i can "inject" my `glossary` object in good letter array for generate an glossary ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why does each letter in the array then have an array for the object? Is it possible there will be multiple title/answer for each letter?

Comment: Yes, possible 10 object of title/answer, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can group array elements by some feature. Example using lodash:

```
var messages = [
    {title: 'Abnfbjbf', message: 'message'},
    {title: 'Abnfbjbf22', message: 'message2'},
    {title: 'Bbnfbjbf', message: 'message3'},
    {title: 'Cbnfbjbf', message: 'message4'}
]
var result = _.groupBy(messages, function(x) {return x.title[0]})
```

where result will contain a map with only non empty letters:

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "message": "message",
            "title": "Abnfbjbf"
        },
        {
            "message": "message2",
            "title": "Abnfbjbf22"
        }
    ],
    "B": [
        {
            "message": "message3",
            "title": "Bbnfbjbf"
        }
    ],
    "C": [
        {
            "message": "message4",
            "title": "Cbnfbjbf"
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE, to include all letters, even empty ones, try this:

```
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');
var arr = letters.map(x => ({letter: x, messages: messages.filter(m=>m.title[0] === x)}))
var result = _.mapValues(_.keyBy(arr, 'letter'), 'messages')
```

Comment: Hey, thank you Ali ! I've already test this approch, but the problem is it an object. I need to `map` and array in my React view :(

Comment: what does "the problem is it an object" mean? It will work anywhere js works, including react.